# Spring Data Redis and Jedis Compatibility issue

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to Create a JedisConnection factory from a RedisClusterConfiguration(Pseudo code given below ) but I face a compile time error

> The type redis.clients.jedis.JedisShardInfo cannot be resolved.It is
>   indirectly referenced from a required .class files.

Code Snippet:

```
RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterList);
return new JedisConnectionFactory(clusterConfiguration);
```

Spring Data Redis version being used : 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: This error gets resolved when I import a Jedis client (version 2.9.0). But breaks at a different point during runtime. I am curious to know If the jedis client is really necessary when I have a spring data redis dependency.

Comment: I'm having similar problem. You have got the solution for the question u posted?

Answer (score 11):

As you can see here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/pom.xml#L75

Jedis client is set as an optional dependency.

In your own project, you need to import the Jedis client. If using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Jedis client is necessary because Spring Data Redis is an umbrella project supporting multiple drivers (Jedis, Lettuce...). Importing all the drivers would be cumbersome. It's up to you to decide what driver to use.

Comment: Ah, i missed the optional parameter. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

You can check in pom of `spring-data-redis` which version of `jedis` it is using and start using the same. This will guarantee there are no conflicts.