# Application not deploying on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache-tomee, spring-data-redis

I am trying to run an application on tomcat server. The application was earlier running on Jboss EAP. All the configuration changes have been made in the tomcat context.xml and other application related configuration files like web.xml, etc. The only ERROR and SEVERE logs that I see when the application is being deployed are mentioned below:

> [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context
> initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'redisCacheManager' defined in class path
> resource [config/serviceContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.tcs.cdm.cache.CacheManager]: Constructor threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:     The type redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig cannot be
> resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> . . .
>
> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'redisCacheManager' defined in class path
> resource [config/serviceContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.tcs.cdm.cache.CacheManager]: Constructor threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:     The type redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig cannot be
> resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> . . .
>
> SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be
> found in the appropriate container log file
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
> [/AppName] startup failed due to previous errors

I have gone through several threads but did not find any solution working for me. I have tried making version changes to jsf related jars in my pom.xml but that also doesn't help. I am currently using tomcat version 9.0.36 but have also tried TomEE 8.0.8 for the same but facing the same issue in both the cases. It would be great if someone could guide as to why this error is coming or a possible solution for the same.

Comment: Seems, jedis jar is missing. Please make sure you have added jedis jar. If you are using maven, follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114059/1545758 this step.
If jedis jar is proper, please make sure that you are able to connect redis server from both remote and local machine.

Comment: It seems that something is missing **at compile time**, and that is giving compilation errors that you are ignoring.  You should fix those compilation errors *before* you attempt to deploy the app.